# Like button: admin page link don't show up

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I've a problem with Facebook page create with a like button, admin don't show up. ([here some test url](http://chat-norvegien-skadi.com/auteur.htm))

I've try unelike, reload, like, reload, and so, and so, but the link admin page don't show up bellow the like button. And i can't access the admin page by Facebook.com.

The fb:admins tag is correct, my user id too.

Help ?

Comment: How can we know if we are not admins? I don't understand your question completely.

Comment: If you are admins of a page create by a like button, you can see a link "administrator page" bellow the button. And the page show up in your page manager on Facebook. Here that's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard of people having problems with the "Moderator" and "Admin" links not appearing.

I suggest logging out from facebook and logging in again.

If you're looking for  general stats on the number of likes for your registered domains, you can go to http://www.facebook.com/insights/

Comment: Hi @Coulton, thx for yout help.  I've tried delog.relog but no change at all.  In fact i need to access the admin page, to notify the "likers" with a new status.  Does someone already solve this kind of problem?